# MS Access : Add Select All to combo box

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

i tried this : 
To add an (All) item to the list, return to Design view and select the combo box control. Then, replace the Row Source property with the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT City FROM Employees 
UNION SELECT "(All)" FROM Employees;
```

from here :  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140084%28v=office.10%29.aspx

My Sql statement looks like this :

```
SELECT LastName FROM Employee  
UNION SELECT "(All)" FROM Employee;
```

I can see the (All) in my drop down,the problem is when I select the Option (All) i receive a blank page.

Am I missing something? Do I need some VBA Code ? This is my current Code:

```
Private Sub cboFilter2_AfterUpdate()
Dim myFilter As String
myFilter = "Select * from Employee_Filter_Query where ([LastName] = '" & cboFilter2 & "')"
Me.Employee_Filter_subform.Form.RecordSource = myFilter
Me.Employee_Filter_subform.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

Br,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely do not have a last name of "(All)" and SQL doesn't automatically know to select everything when you pick "(All)" form the combobox. You'll need to adapt your query:

```
"Select * from Employee_Filter_Query where ([LastName] = iif('" & cboFilter2 & "'='(All)',[LastName],'" & cboFilter2 & "'))"
```

WHat this will do is look for the combobox to say "(All)" and if it does then match `[LastName] = [LastName]` which will always be true and return all records, otherwise it will match `[LastName]` against your filter and act like normal.

An alternative is to set up like this:

```
If cboFinter2 = "(All)" Then
    myFilter = "Select * from Employee_Filter_Query"
Else
    myFilter = "Select * from Employee_Filter_Query where ([LastName] = '" & cboFilter2 & "')"
End If
```

Comment: It works! thanks a lot:) I also have a print button which opens a print preview form based on the Filter.Do you have any Ideas on how to add (all) to my expression ? current expression : [LastName]=[TempVars]![TempLastNameType]

Comment: Or you could just not include a `WHERE` clause if cboFilter2 = *"(ALL)"*